# What is the true name of the Elders in the ExForce book series?

Tags: exforce

In the book series ExForce, there is an Elder species but they're always called "The Elders".  I'm not sure if I've missed anything in the books or supporting material.  If I did though, does anyone (aside from Craig Alanson) know their true name for their species?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't missed anything, they haven't been named yet.

The next few books (Brushfire onward) should deal with the Elders in depth, expanding the detail we have of them.

Update:  in the most recent book, Failure Mode, we have been given a name for the Elders - “Quornaxalicevivon”.

Comment: t minus 5 days...... :-)

Comment: @DanCsharpster two years later, and coming up to the final book, and they still havent been named...

Comment: I know.  :-/  I was hoping for a little bit more by now.  This book is gonna have to be a whirlwind of content and even then, fans will be asking for more.

Comment: yes, they said it roughly translates to "first ones" or Elders.  Which I guess is okay.  I'm not sure I was expecting any really cool Hodor type revelation there or anything.

Comment: @DanCsharpster it was about the only part of the final book that I found interesting…

Comment: Ouch.  You made it all the way to the end and it was still that bad for you?  Did you not like the rest and just powered through them as well?  What were you expecting to have happen?

Comment: @DanCsharpster I think the conclusion to the Elder story was rushed, the deaths unnecessary, and the fact that nothing else was resolved frustrating.  To the point where its put me off from the author now.  I liked the series in general, although it was dragging in the final few books, and the one-upmanship in terms of deus ex machina endings was becoming monotonous (ie earth is threatened, oh look in the final few pages we now have Elder weapons, earth is threatened, that didnt work out, oh look in the final few pages we now have a Sentinel, that didnt work out… etc)

Comment: yeah I can see that.  Dragging out Elder weapons, a sentinel, etc at last minute seemed like he was using MacGuffins aka (plot coupons) to wrap up that episode.  I get that some series leave off at cliffhangers in case they pick it up later or so fans can continue the story in their minds, but I was hoping for a bit more interaction with the Elders and maybe some more info about the intelligence from outside the galaxy.

I'm also not a professional storywriter so what do I know.  One of the best tie-ins in recent memory was Hodor in GOT.  I want more stories like that.

Comment: @DanCsharpster the final book was just pointless escalation after pointless escalation, each with its fairly immediate escalated resolution, and then we get a partial wrap up in like the last 10% of the book - pretty much involving nothing discussed before.  Lets kill off this character, then lets kill off this character, then lets kill off all these characters, then lets kill off this big character... oh, wait, lets bring most of (but not all) them back.

Comment: @DanCsharpster and the "reasoning" for the barrier and the ascension is just ... 2d in nature.  The Elders panicked because they met someone that was more powerful than them, so they built the barrier and ascended to get away from it because they assumed it was hostile....  How immature does that make the Elder civilisation?

Comment: it sounds like a voluntary Matrix.  Where they just plugged themselves into a hedonistic VR.  If they were such masters of physics and technology and now they have these expanded consciousnesses, shouldn't they have been developing some insane tech over the millions of years they were up there?  Enough to go smoothly back and forth between the normal dimensions and the higher ones?  And then come back and defeat the extra-galactic threats?  I really wanted to hear more about that threat and what their deal was.  It would have been funny if they were benevolent neighbors all along.